# BST String Traversal

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I'm trying to implement an inorder, preorder, and postorder traversal algorithm for my BST. It seems that the inorder algorithm is working so far, but it's only returning the first character of the word. I realize that I'm returning `char c`, but I'm confused on how I would make it return the entire word. Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
package main;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

// Node class
class Node
{
    char c;
    boolean end; 
    Node left, right;

    public Node(char c)
    {
        this.c = c;
        this.end = false;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;

    }          
}


class BinarySearchTree
{
    private Node root;

    public BinarySearchTree()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public void addValue(String s)
    { 
            root = addValue(root, s, 0); 
    }

    private Node addValue(Node x, String s, int d)
    {
            char c = s.charAt(d);
            if (x == null) 
        x = new Node(c);
            if (c < x.c) 
        x.left = addValue(x.left, s, d);
            else if (c > x.c) 
        x.right = addValue(x.right, s, d);
            else x.end = true;
                return x;
    }

    public boolean search(String s)
    { 
            return search(root, s, 0); 
    }

    private boolean search(Node x, String s, int d)
    {
            if (x == null) 
        return false;

            char c = s.charAt(d);

            if (c < x.c) 
                return search(x.left, s, d);   
            else if (c > x.c) 
                return search(x.right, s, d);
            else 
                return x.end;

    }

        public void inorder(){
            inorder(root);
        }

        private void inorder(Node r){
            if (r != null){
                inorder(r.left);
                System.out.print(r.c);
                inorder(r.right);
            }
        }
} 

public class Project2
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BinarySearchTree tree  = new BinarySearchTree(); // Make new BST object

        // Variable for scanned word
        String token = "";

        // Use scanner for input file
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("10words.txt")).useDelimiter("\\s+"); 

        //Check for next line in text file
        while (scan.hasNext()) 
        {
            token = scan.next();
            tree.addValue(token);
        }
        scan.close();

        tree.inorder();

        Scanner inputWord = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nEnter a word to search: ");
    String word = inputWord.next().toLowerCase();

    if(tree.search(word) == false){
            System.out.println("Word NOT Found!");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Word Found!");
        }
        inputWord.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not look at your inorder code but you said it works so I'll believe you.

However I did take a look at your addValue code and you only save the first character here. No wonder you can't get the entire word back, you just don't save it :P

Instead, you should change your Node class to accept a String instead of a character. You won't need the d parameter in your addValue method then either.

The Java String class provides the .compareTo () method in order to lexicographically compare Strings. You can use it with string.compareTo(otherString)

This method will return a value < 0, equal to 0 or > 0.

```
< 0 means string is lexicographically smaller than otherString (for example: "Apple" would be smaller than "Banana")

= 0 means it's the exact same word

> 0 means string is bigger than otherString (for example: "Banana" would be bigger than "Apple")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was on the verge of starting completely over. That was way easier than I thought. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

your addValue method looks like it is incorrect. it only modifies the root, then character will be equal, so it returns. In particular d is never modified.

On a more fondamental level, a BST would be appropriate to look for a character in a tree, not for looking for a String. If you want to look for a word, you can use a Trie instead (which is not a binary tree).

Comment: That's actually not true. I admit it's a very odd kind of code but if you look at it closely you'll realize it actually will work. Even though I don't get why he's only writing the first character of his string into the tree and why he has the d parameter that he never changes, but at least it will actually add a full tree (in a incredibly odd way). Keep in mind what you just described only happens the first time he runs this method. The second time, x will not equal null, so he won't replace it and instead either continue with the left or the right child.

Comment: I agree a Trie would be much easier to use, but the assignment specifically states to use a BST. Some of the code was given to us, which is why it only adding a character confuses me. I'm considering rewriting my own entire code, if it's deemed to crazy to mess with.

Comment: when calling addValue("Test"), only the 't' will be put in the tree. So it does not really make any sense...

Comment: If you really need to use a BST, then the value at the node should be the word (String), not a character.